# URL rewrite to fix broken links into a subdirectory -- subdirectory was moved to the root directory

Tags: redirects, mod-rewrite

I had an e-commerce website hosted on `http://mydomain.com/beta` for more than a year, eventually I decided to move the website to root `http://mydomain.com`

I had done quite a lot of link postings to forums etc, when my site used to be hosted in the sub-dir /beta.

Is there a way to do a mod_rewrite by which all the old links that I have posted do not return as broken links, since now longer the site is hosted in /beta and is now hosted on the site root.

I did read that mod_rewrite can help resolve this issue, but also read about that this has to be done with care. Just a tip that this site is using friendly URL.

Answer (score 1):

The rules below will redirect (301, permanent redirect -- will change address in URL bar as well) all incoming requests from `http://www.example.com/beta/` to `http://www.example.com/`

```
# activate rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# redirect from /beta/ to /
RewriteRule ^beta/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

If you need just rewrite (so URL stays the same in browser's adderss bar -- i.e. still contains `/beta/`) then replace last line by this:

```
RewriteRule ^beta/(.*)$ /$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to overcomplicate matters, the one 'redirect' line will deal with everything in your sub directories and do the 301 thing:

```
Redirect permanent /beta /
```